# How to restrict input into numbers only c++

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a way to prevent the program from executing characters in "Menu" type program where you choose options while running console and enter numbers only to do steps and browse data.

My program is a book catalog where you can review, change, add or delete information.

Things wouldn't be as bad but the the thing is, that when you enter a letter or non-number character the program gets messy and stuck.

I am not adding my code since I think that there should be a universal command to get rid of my problem + it would take some time to translate my code into EN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is use the getline function I think. Instead of using cin >> num; for example, you would use getline(cin,value); where "value" is a string that you first store your input in. Then you can do num = atoi(value.c_str()); to save the string input as an integer value into "num". If "num" is a float, then just use atof instead of atoi. This way if the string is not a number, it just sets the value to 0. You could then use an if statement to display an error message if the value of num == 0. Hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs in a console and you are worried about wrong (non-number) input, perhaps you should the input not as a number, but as a text and then parse it to see it is really a number. If not, tell the user the input is incorrect and let them enter it again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip <3